Reusable Database updating method
I have a method which could be used through out different instances to update the table.
public async Task<bool> UpdateValues(string tableName, string keyColumn, string key, object model)
        {
            var columnValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            var properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach(var prop in properties)
            {
                var value = prop.GetValue(model);

                if (prop.Name != "ORDER_NUMBER")
                {
                    columnValues.Add(prop.Name.ToLower(), value ?? DBNull.Value);
                }
            }

            var setClauses = new List<string>();
            foreach(var column in columnValues.Keys)
            {
                setClauses.Add($"{column} = @{column}");
            }

            string setClause = string.Join(",", setClauses);

            string query = $"UPDATE {tableName} SET {setClause} WHERE {keyColumn} = @key";

            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);
                foreach(var column in columnValues)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{column.Key}", column.Value);
                }

                if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                }

                int rowsAffected = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                if(rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success! Details have been UPDATED.");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        }

Here the ORDER_NUMBER should not be updated. Therefore I have to omit the ORDER_NUMBER this way. Well if I do this I won't be able to use this method at different instances. Need expert advice here on, if I'm to make this method reusable on multiple instances particularly at one instance if I'm to use this method, in a way that ORDER_NUMBER field should not be updated. how can I do that? Following is the way I'm using the method inside of main method.
private async void Submit()
        {          
            string tableName = "tableName";
            string keyColumn = "unique_number";

            var columns = new List<string> { "Id", "delivered_date" };

            var result = await _db.ReadValues(tableName, keyColumn, SerialNumber, columns);           

            if (result.Count > 0)
            {
                string id = result["Id"].ToString();

                DateTime deliveredDate;
                DateTime.TryParse(result["delivered_date"].ToString(), out deliveredDate);

                
                if(deliveredDate == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    //var infoToUpdate = new InfoModel
                    //{
                    //    Unique_Id = _infoModel.Unique_Id,
                    //    Web_Login = _infoModel.Web_Login,
                    //    IMEI = _infoModel.IMEI,
                    //    MAC = _infoModel.MAC,                    
                    //};                   
                   

                    await _db.UpdateValues(tableName, "Id", id, _deviceInfo);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    await _db.InsertValues(tableName, _deviceInfo);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _db.InsertValues(tableName, _deviceInfo);
            }            
        }

As you could see I have commented out the model which I pass which retrieves the value and update the table. The model contains ORDER_NUMBER as well and I have omitted that out. When updating the values the method should avoid updating ORDER_NUMBER and not change its value. Since I'm creating new instance of the model ORDER_NUMBER becomes null and when updating a null value of ORDER_NUMBER is getting inserted which is replacing the ORDER_NUMBER value which is already there instead of being avoided.
The code snippet I have provided is .net wpf c# adhering to MVVM architecture pattern. And I'm inserting values to MySQL database.

Short answer: If you don't want a value in your model to be changed, don't expose a setter. If the value is something like a Computed or Identity column in  the database then use an attribute on the property to tell your code iterating through the reflected properties what to ignore. I.e.
[DatabaseGemerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] // or DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity
public int Order_Number { get; private set; }

Shorter answer: Use Entity Framework. EF manages all of this and more than you're bound to write yourself. (EF uses the attributes in the example above) EF's change tracker also supports read-only fields. If you expose no public setter then the Order_Number cannot change, and any generated UPDATE sql statement won't even include it. The UPDATE statement is generated on for values that actually changed, and only if any value has changed.
